Model structure on Functors from Span to chain complexes
Given Span category ($1 \leftarrow 0 \rightarrow 2$) and the following model structure on chain complexes $Ch_{\mathbb{K}}$:

Fibrations: level wise surjective.
Cofibrations: level wise injective.
Weak equivalences: quasi isomorphism.

I'd like to prove that Fun(Span,$Ch_{\mathbb{K}}$)admits a model structure given by:

Fibrations: object wise fibrations.
Weak equivalences: object wise weak equivalences.

Going through the four axioms the one I've been struggling is the lifting property. Since I want to show $Fib \subset RLP(Cof \cap WE) = RLP(LLP(Fib \cap WE) \cap WE)$ I'd like to understand how to prove this part.
In particular, I don't see how from the definition this could be deduced, and any advice on that direction would be useful. A thing that I thought is to find an adjunction so that I can show that the one I'm defining is a right transfer induced model structure, but the one I found is $Cst_{Span}\dashv lim_{Span}$ which doesn't seem to help since I don't have a nice representation of limit as I have with colimit, i.e pushout. Is this second way a cumberstone?
Any help would be appreciated.

The model structure you are after is the projective model structure on a functor category. It exists in this case because of a general existence theorem, so you can look up the proof of that (for example in Hirschhorn's model category book, theorem 11.6.1) to see why your particular lifting property holds. (That you can apply this general theorem to your particular case is shown here, after you restrict to the special case where $R$ is a field.)

Thanks for the reference, I'm no very used to this notation or theorems, do you know a simpler way to describe without invoking way too general theorem?  Also I don't understand whether you replied to the second approach, thanks!
